# Задачка на питоне. Перемещение групп символов в строке

Tags: python

Дана строка, допустим ABCDEFG
Далее у нас появляется переменная, допустим i = 'E'
Значит далее должно получится FGEABCD
Как такое реализовать для разных букв и для разной длины строки(или массива)

Answer (score 1):

```
def move_chars(s: str, i: str) -> str: 
    index = s.index(i) 
    return s[index+1:] + i + s[:index] 
print('cтрока') 
s = input()
print('буква')
i = input() 
result = move_chars(s, i) 
print('Новая строка',result)
```